Understanding C11's _Generic
The C17 Standard requires that, in a _Generic expression,

No two generic associations in the same generic selection shall
specify compatible types. The type of the controlling expression is
the type of the expression as if it had undergone an lvalue conversion
[....]

@Davilsor in this post: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/289337/265278 states that:

_Generic is really only intended to make the implementation of <math.h> more portable, so I don’t entirely trust it with integral types. I’d be especially wary of char and short int getting widened to int.

If uint64_t is a typedef for say unsigned long long int, and I have both of them in some _Generic expression, would that go against "No two generic associations in the same generic selection shall specify compatible types"? If it does, what behavior should I expect? Compilation to fail? Undefined Behavior? A diagnostic?
Take this for example:
#define map(count, iter, func) _Generic (*iter,   \
                                char: map_c,    \
                                unsigned char: map_uc,  \
                                short int: map_si,   \
                                unsigned short int: map_usi,    \
                                int: map_i, \
                                unsigned int: map_ui,   \
                                long int: map_li,   \
                                unsigned long int: map_uli, \
                                long long int: map_lli,     \
                                unsigned long long int: map_ulli,   \
                                float: map_f,   \
                                double: map_d,  \
                                long double: map_ld,    \
                                _Bool: map_b,    \
                                char *: map_s   \
                            )(count, iter, func)

Is there anything that could potentially go wrong in the above _Generic expression, especially if I add fixed-width integer types from stdint.h to it?

There are three char types, two of which have the same range.  But that is tangential to your question.

@JonathanLeffler In "doc/generic11.c" in your "soq" repository, you've used (x) + (y) as the controlling expression. But would that not have undefined behavior for signed types on overflow? If so, is there a way to avoid it?

As with almost any expression involving signed integer types, yes, there is a risk of overflow.  You deal with it the same way you deal with risk with int z = x+ y; — you can ignore it or use the checked arithmetic functions from C23 or do other testing as seems appropriate.

@JonathanLeffler Do you know if the C23 "checked arithmetic functions" are implemented by any standard lib yet? I haven't seen a compiler supporting them.

@Lundin https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-14/changes.html says that GCC 14 has implemented <stdckdint.h>.

@Lundin https://releases.llvm.org/18.1.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html says that Clang 18.1 also has implemented <stdckdint.h>.

@Jonathan I built on top of your generic macro and ended up with one that works for all integer types (including _Bool), works with mixed signed and unsigned types,  and has no integer overflow. Thought you might be interested in seeing it: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/292409/generic-max-function-for-integer-types-including-boolean

Note that §6.5.1.1 Generic selection ¶3 says: The controlling expression of a generic selection is not evaluated.. Since it isn't evaluated, it can't overflow.  It makes sense.  The controlling expression determines the type at compile time; overflow happens at run-time.

@JonathanLeffler I see, so addition was never a problem. _Generic has a lot of rules, but has been very useful to me. Thanks.

Since I’m name-checked, there are several good answers that I learned from. C17 changed the wording about what conversions the type of the controlling expression undergoes, and I wasn’t up-to-date on it.


If uint64_t is a typedef for say unsigned long long int, and I have both of them in some _Generic expression, would that go against "No two generic associations in the same generic selection shall specify compatible types"?

Yes.

If it does, what behavior should I expect? Compilation to fail? Undefined Behavior? A diagnostic?

A diagnostic message and most compilers will refuse to compile the program.

Is there anything that could potentially go wrong in the above _Generic expression,

No, not as its currently written.

especially if I add fixed-width integer types from stdint.h to it?

Yes, then you will have problems since you will then specify the same type more than once so you'll get diagnostic messages and the program will likely fail to compile.

"you will have problems since you will then specify the same type more than once" Assuming we speak of the intn_t/uintn_t types - the so called fixed-width ones - then they will not get the same type twice by definition. All types from int8_t to int64_t will be unique types. So it will work just fine. But in case of int_leastn_t/int_fastn_t, several types in the _Generic association list might collide.

@Lundin OP asks what will happen when adding the fixed width types to the list that already covers the fundamental types.

Ah ok fair enough, yes there will definitely be collisions then.

@Ted Lyngmo well answers OP's explicit questions.
Yet it remains unanswered the implied question: how to use _Generic to steer code when uint64_t does not match any standard types?
Use more levels
At the top level, map(), add a default: that steers code among uint64_t, uint32_t, etc.  This can even be carried to additional levels for size_t, uintmax_t that might collide with prior types.
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int map_uc(int, unsigned char*, int);
int map_usi(int, unsigned short*, int);
int map_ui(int, unsigned*, int);
int map_uli(int, unsigned long*, int);
int map_ulli(int, unsigned long long*, int);
int map_u8(int, uint8_t*, int);
int map_u16(int, uint16_t*, int);
int map_u32(int, uint32_t*, int);
int map_u64(int, uint64_t*, int);

#define map2(iter) _Generic (*(iter),   \
    uint8_t: map_u8,  \
    uint16_t: map_u16,  \
    uint32_t: map_u32,  \
    uint64_t: map_u64    \
    )

#define map(count, iter, func) _Generic (*(iter),   \
    unsigned char: map_uc,  \
    unsigned short int: map_usi,    \
    unsigned int: map_ui,   \
    unsigned long int: map_uli, \
    unsigned long long int: map_ulli,   \
    default: map2(iter)   \
    ) ((count), (iter), (func))

int main(void) {
  uint64_t sz = 123;
  uint64_t *xx = &sz;
  printf("%d\n", map(0, xx, 0));
  return 0;
}


Regarding integer types, _Generic and stdint.h, there seems to be a few misconceptions.

_Generic does not type-promote the first item in the association list (but puts it through "lvalue conversion" meaning it discards type qualifiers).
Be aware however that if you pass an expression to it, then that
expression in itself might contain implicit type promotions. For example
_Generic((signed char){}, ... will result in a signed char but
_Generic(+(signed char){}, ... will result in an int. Which of course has nothing to do with _Generic in itself.

For the standard "primitive" integer data types of C, all of them will be unique types in relation to each other: signed char, short, int, long and long long. Even though some may have the same size, they will have different conversion rank so _Generic must treat them all as distinct types.

For the stdint.h types, they will be implemented as typedef corresponding to the "primitive" data types (C17 7.20 §4), meaning you can't have for example int and int16_t in the same _Generic association list, portably. They may or may not be the same type.

It is mandatory for any C compiler to provide int8_t, int16_t, int32_t and int64_t if a corresponding type exists at the target system hardware level. These are exact-width types and so all of them are unique types in relation to each other, given that the type exists on the specific system.

The mandatory int_leastn_t and int_fastn_t types may however be duplicates of each other.


Summary:
Well-defined and 100% portable without diagnostics raised:
_Generic((x), 
  signed char: 0,
  short: 0,
  int: 0,
  long: 0,
  long long: 0)

_Generic((x), 
  int8_t:  0,
  int16_t: 0,
  int32_t: 0,
  int64_t: 0)

(Though obscure/exotic systems need not provide all of the stdint.h exact-width types.)
